# Ubuntu 12.04.2 server edition minimum specification?

Tags: installation, server

I have an old PC that I was planning too setup as a NAS system and I'm not really up there on tech knowledge.

I was wondering could someone please give me some guidance as to what the minimum specifications this computer would require to run the server edition of Ubuntu, or will the Ubuntu server run at all on a really old PC.

Comment: Take a look at the [Ubuntu 12.04 Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Ubuntu website](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer#System_Requirement), you need 128MB RAM. You also need a Pentium II or higher processor. I regularly use Ubuntu 12.04 server on a 512MB virtual server, running LAMP applications without any issues.

Comment: Note that minimum specs aren't necessarily *recommended* specs.  Depending on what you are planning on running, you should have varying specs.